# Invoke-RestMethod : Could not find authentication data on request when send to headers

Tags: powershell, post, azure-devops, http-headers

I added powershell script in azure devops release and try to send POST request using Invoke-WebRequest with Authorization token and xml file.

What am I doing wrong?

I get Authorization token from another POST request and tried to create headers with this token and trying send xml file using x-ray endpoint (NUnit XML results - POST /api/v1/import/execution/nunit)
https://confluence.xpand-it.com/display/XRAYCLOUD/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST#ImportExecutionResults-REST-NUnitXMLresults

Authorization token like headers parameters
Content-type like powershell parameters

```
$bodyForAuth=@{"client_id"="...";
"client_secret"="...";
}
$jsonAuth=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $urlForAuth -Method POST -Body ($bodyForAuth|ConvertTo-Json) -ContentType "application/json"
$authToken=ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $jsonAuth

$headers=@{ Authorization = "Bearer $authToken" }

Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $headers -Uri $urlForXrayApi -Method POST -ContentType "text/xml" -InFile $TestResultsXmlPath
```

And I have error: "Invoke-RestMethod : Could not find authentication data on request"

Also I try to send like this:

```
$headers=@{ Authorization = "Bearer $authToken";"Content-Type"="text/xml" }

Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $headers -Uri $urlForXrayApi -Method POST -InFile $TestResultsXmlPath
```

And also have the same error : `"Invoke-RestMethod : Could not find authentication data on request"`

But if I send POST request like this (without Content-Type):

```
$bodyForAuth=@{"client_id"="...";
"client_secret"="...";
}
$jsonAuth=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $urlForAuth -Method POST -Body ($bodyForAuth|ConvertTo-Json) -ContentType "application/json"
$authToken=ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $jsonAuth

$headers=@{ Authorization = "Bearer $authToken" }

Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $headers -Uri $urlForXrayApi -Method POST -InFile $TestResultsXmlPath
```

I have SERVER ERROR: `"Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":"Missing data in the nunit results import request"}"`

Power Shell v. 5.1

Why when I send to headers server can not fine authorization data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed parenthesis, so I changed `$TestResultsXmlPath` to `$(TestResultsXmlPath)`

```
Invoke-WebRequest `
    -Headers $headers `
    -Uri $urlForXrayApi `
    -Method POST `
    -InFile $(TestResultsXmlPath)
```